# How to grab the pointer on Wayland like Gnome does?

Tags: linux, gnome, wayland

It specifically says in the [Wayland TODO text file](https://github.com/nobled/wayland/blob/master/TODO#L110) that Wayland doesn't have active grabs for the pointer yet. But if I run Gnome on Wayland, try clicking a menu open and then clicking outside it, the outside click is swallowed as if the pointer was grabbed by the menu window. How does Gnome manage that?

Comment: You shouldn't be running software that is clunky and incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about can be done very easily by creating a transparent overlay over the entire screen. In that case, the click events on the transparent region will not propagate to the underlying elements. You can see this in Telegram's image viewer, where it creates a full-screen gray overlay under the image.

But on the compositor side this effect can be achieved in a different way-- by disabling all input events outside the popup rectangle.